# Contar frecuencia de bases en fichero de registros

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy buscando la manera de mejorar el siguiente fragmento de código de tal manera que en lugar de hacer un recuento total de bases de todos los registros encontrados lo haga por registro. Por otra parte también me gustaría hacerlo sensible a un tipo de registro u otro. Por ejemplo en mi caso si en alguna linea que no sea la cabecera ('>') del registro aparece una U seria un registro de tipo RNA si no hay ninguna seria de tipo DNA, pero para esto ultimo estoy teniendo problemas con el nivel de sangrado.

Este es mi código:

```
import os


def registros(fichero):
    registros = 0 
    try:
        with open(fichero, 'r') as f:
            if os.path.isfile(fichero) == True: 
                print('Se encontró Fichero Fasta:',fichero)
            lineas = f.readlines() 
            for l in lineas:  
                if l.startswith('>'): 
                    registros += 1 inicial
                else:
                    continue 
    except FileNotFoundError: 
        print('El fichero introducido no se ha encontrado, asegúrese de que se encuentra en ese directorio!')

    return registros

def numero_bases(fichero):
    A = 0
    T = 0
    C = 0
    G = 0
    U = 0
   try: 
       with open(fichero, 'r') as f: 
       lineas = f.readlines() 
       for l in lineas:
            if not l.startswith('>'):
                for base in l:
                    if base  == 'A':
                        A += 1
                    elif base == 'T':
                        T += 1
                    elif base == 'G':
                        G += 1
                    elif base == 'C':
                        C += 1
                    elif base == 'U':
                        U += 1

            else:
                continue

    except FileNotFoundError: 
        print('Pruebe a Introducir un fichero existente')

    return 'con el siguiente contenido de bases:\nAdenina: {}\nTimina: {}\nCitosina: {}\nGuanina: {}\nUracilo: {}'.format(A, T, C, G, U)


while True:
    fichero = input('Introduzca nombre del fichero FASTA(q para salir):\n')
    if fichero == 'q':
        break
    print('El fichero',fichero, 'contiene',registros(fichero),'registros', numero_bases(fichero))
```

Un ejemplo para el fichero llamado 2.fasta que tiene este contenido sería asi:

```
>YAL069W-1.334 Putative promoter sequence
CCACUG
CCACGG

>YAL068C-7235.2170 Putative promoter sequence
TACGC
TACGGG
```

La entrada de los datos seria del tipo:

```
Introduzca nombre del fichero FASTA(q para salir):
2.fasta
```

La salida de los datos debería ser algo como esto:

```
Se encontró Fichero Fasta: 2.fasta
El fichero 2.fasta contiene 2 registros con el siguiente contenido de bases:
>YAL069W-1.334 Putative promoter sequence:
Es un registro de tipo RNA:
Adenina: 2
Timina: 0
Citosina: 6
Guanina: 3
Uracilo: 1
>YAL068C-7235.2170 Putative promoter sequence:
Es un registro de tipo DNA:
Adenina: 2
Timina: 2
Citosina: 3
Guanina: 4
Uracilo: 0
```

Los registros de tipo RNA tienen U en lugar de T y viceversa con los registros de tipo DNA.

Comment: Hola Steve, en estos casos siempre es útil que pongas un ejemplo de entrada y que salida esperas para esa entrada. Entiendo más u menos lo que deseas, pero no se como quieres la salida. Seria bueno que pusieras un txt con registros tipo ADN y ARN y que salida esperarias de ese ejemplo (¿qué se debería imprimir exactamente? ¿Se imprimen las bases de cada registro por separado, se suman todas las que pertenecen a ADN por un lado y las ARN por otro?). Un saludo.

Comment: Es cierto, olvidé comentar el tipo de salida esperada. He modificado el codigo. La salida deberia algo del estilo que he puesto. Un saludo

Comment: steve ¿cada registro (lo que hay entre lineas que empiezan por >) es una sola linea o varias? ¿El nombre del registro se toma del txt o se numera empezando por 1 simplemente? Si pones un ejemplo de txt es más fácil de reproducir.

Comment: los registros pueden tener mas de una linea. El nombre del registro se puede usar la cabecera del mismo o como un numero empezando por el 1, eso es relativamente irrelevante. He editado el codigo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `collections.Counter` para contar las bases de cada línea. Para saber si es ARN u ADN basta con que comprobemos si la clave "U" está o no en el diccionario.

También es importante, sobre todo si vas a trabajar con archivos relativamente grandes, no recorrerlos más de una vez.

Hay múltiples formas de organizar el código, una de ellas puede ser:

```
import collections
import os



def registros(fichero):
    registros = collections.OrderedDict()
    contador = 0
    for linea in fichero:
        if linea.startswith('>'):
            contador += 1
            registros[contador] = collections.Counter()
        else:
            registros[contador].update(linea)
    return registros

def parse_fasta(path):
    try:
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            if os.path.isfile(path): 
                print('Se encontró Fichero Fasta:', fichero)
                regs = registros(f)
                print("El fichero {} contiene {} registros con el siguiente contenido de bases:".format(fichero, len(regs)))
                for reg, bases in regs.items():
                    print("  Registro {}:".format(reg))
                    if "U" in bases:
                        print("   Es un registro de tipo ARN:")
                        print("    Adenina:  {}\n    Uracilo:  {}\n    Citosina: {}\n    Guanina:  {}\n".format(bases["A"],
                                                                                                                bases["U"], 
                                                                                                                bases["C"], 
                                                                                                                bases["G"]))
                    else:
                        print("   Es un registro de tipo ADN:")
                        print("    Adenina:  {}\n    Timina:   {}\n    Citosina: {}\n    Guanina:  {}\n".format(bases["A"],
                                                                                                                bases["T"], 
                                                                                                                bases["C"], 
                                                                                                                bases["G"]))
            else:
                print("La ruta no se corresponde con un fichero.")

    except FileNotFoundError: 
        print('El fichero introducido no se ha encontrado, asegúrese de que se encuentra en ese directorio!')

while True:
    fichero = input('Introduzca nombre del fichero FASTA(q para salir):\n')
    if fichero == 'q':
        break
    parse_fasta(fichero)
```

La salida para tu ejemplo es:

> ```
> >>> Introduzca nombre del fichero FASTA(q para salir):
> 2.fasta
> Se encontró Fichero Fasta: 2.fasta
> El fichero 2.fasta contiene 2 registros con el siguiente contenido de bases:
>   Registro 1:
>    Es un registro de tipo ARN:
>     Adenina:  2
>     Uracilo:  1
>     Citosina: 6
>     Guanina:  3
>
>   Registro 2:
>    Es un registro de tipo ADN:
>     Adenina:  2
>     Timina:   2
>     Citosina: 3
>     Guanina:  4
> ```

Si quieres que el registro sea nombrado según la cabecera (siempre que las cabeceras dentro de un fichero sean únicas) puedes modificar la función `registros`:

```
def registros(fichero):
    registros = collections.OrderedDict()
    for linea in fichero:
        if linea.startswith('>'):
            nombre = linea[1:].strip()
            registros[nombre] = collections.Counter()
        else:
            registros[nombre].update(linea)
    return registros
```

Las función presupone que la primera línea del fichero siempre va a ser una cabecera (o un archivo vacío), nunca una línea en blanco o cualquier otra cosa. Si cabe la posibilidad de que esto no sea así habría que tenerlo en cuenta.